How to fix a problem with my Telegram bot when trying to translate on other language my text?
I have a bot which should answer users' questions by question category, but there is a joke, for some reason it gives a crooked translation (used the google trans library), what's the joke? I scored the gpt chat, he just put comments on me and said everything correctly, and I don't understand why it works that way, but here's an example of a piece of message where the translation is stupid and crooked. I don't understand what the joke is.
Where does he write the "ВОПРЕС" and "OTVET" from???
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 3) Detect language and translating:
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
translator = Translator()

def is_cyrillic(text: str) -> bool:
    cyr_count = sum(1 for ch in text if 'а' <= ch.lower() <= 'я' or ch.lower() == 'ё')
    lat_count = sum(1 for ch in text if 'a' <= ch.lower() <= 'z')
    return cyr_count > lat_count

def detect_user_language_robust(text: str) -> str:
    """
    По умолчанию считаем язык 'en', если не ru/zh.
    """
    t = text.strip()
    if len(t) <= 2:
        if is_cyrillic(t):
            return "ru"
        else:
            return "en"
    try:
        detection = translator.detect(t)
        lang = detection.lang
        logging.debug(f"[detect_user_language_robust] googletrans => {lang}")
        if lang == 'ru':
            return 'ru'
        elif lang.startswith('zh'):
            return 'zh'
        else:
            return "en"
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Language detect error: {e}")
        return "en"

def custom_pre_translate(original_text: str, target_lang: str) -> str:
    """
    Заменяет "Question", "Answer" и другие фразы на локализованные эквиваленты для предотвращения некорректного перевода.
    """
    text = original_text

    if target_lang == 'ru':
        text = text.replace("❓Question:", "❓Вопрос:")
        text = text.replace("✅Answer:", "✅Ответ:")
        text = text.replace(
            "If you haven't found the answer, manager @solomon_bog will contact you soon!",
            "Если вы не нашли ответ, менеджер @solomon_bog свяжется с вами в ближайшее время!"
        )
    elif target_lang == 'zh':
        text = text.replace("❓Question:", "❓问题:")
        text = text.replace("✅Answer:", "✅回答:")
        text = text.replace(
            "If you haven't found the answer, manager @solomon_bog will contact you soon!",
            "如果您没有找到答案，manager @solomon_bog 很快会与您联系！"
        )
    else:
        # target_lang == 'en'
        text = text.replace("❓Вопрос:", "❓Question:")
        text = text.replace("✅Ответ:", "✅Answer:")
        text = text.replace(
            "Если вы не нашли ответ, менеджер @solomon_bog свяжется с вами в ближайшее время!",
            "If you haven't found the answer, manager @solomon_bog will contact you soon!"
        )
    return text

def google_translate_response(original_text, target_lang):
    """
    Переводит текст на target_lang.
    Если target_lang не 'ru', 'zh' или 'en', по умолчанию переводит на 'en'.
    Применяет custom_pre_translate перед переводом для корректной локализации ключевых терминов.
    """
    if not original_text.strip():
        return original_text
    try:
        if target_lang not in ['ru', 'zh', 'en']:
            target_lang = 'en'
        if target_lang == 'zh':
            target_lang = 'zh-cn'
        
        # Предварительная локализация ключевых терминов
        pre_translated_text = custom_pre_translate(original_text, target_lang)
        
        translated = translator.translate(pre_translated_text, dest=target_lang)
        return translated.text
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Ошибка при переводе: {e}")
        return original_text


def build_faq_full_list(category_name, faq_list, lang):
    """
    Формирует полный список FAQ с локализованными метками "Question" и "Answer".
    """
    if lang == 'ru':
        q_label = "❓Вопрос:"
        a_label = "✅Ответ:"
        intro = f"Вот список наиболее часто задаваемых вопросов в категории {category_name}:\n\n"
    elif lang == 'zh':
        q_label = "❓问题:"
        a_label = "✅回答:"
        intro = f"这是类别 {category_name} 中最常见的问题列表：\n\n"
    else:
        # en
        q_label = "❓Question:"
        a_label = "✅Answer:"
        intro = f"Here is the list of the most frequently asked questions in the {category_name} category:\n\n"
    
    lines = [intro]
    for item in faq_list:
        question = item.get("question", "").strip()
        answer_body = item.get("answer", "").strip()

        q_line = f"{q_label} {question}"
        a_line = f"{a_label} {answer_body}"
        lines.append(q_line)
        lines.append(a_line)
        lines.append("")  # пустая строка
    return "\n".join(lines)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 7) Команды и обработчики
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Функция для получения приветственного сообщения на всех трёх языках
def get_greeting_message_all_languages():
    greetings = (
        " Hello!\n\n"
        "I am the digital goods and social media accounts expert at socnet.store, socnet.shop, socnet.pro.\n"
        "I can help answer any questions about these services.\n\n"
        "Please include the category in your question, e.g.: \"How to buy a Facebook account?\".\n"
        "If you do not find the answer, the bot can propose using ChatGPT after 3 failed attempts.\n\n"
        " Привет!\n\n"
        "Я эксперт по цифровым товарам и аккаунтам социальных сетей в socnet.store, socnet.shop, socnet.pro.\n"
        "Я могу помочь ответить на любые вопросы об этих услугах.\n\n"
        "Пожалуйста, указывайте категорию в вашем вопросе, например: \"Как купить аккаунт Facebook?\".\n"
        "Если вы не найдете ответа, бот может предложить использовать ChatGPT после 3 неудачных попыток.\n\n"
        " 你好！\n\n"
        "我是 socnet.store、socnet.shop 和 socnet.pro 的数字商品和社交媒体账户专家。\n"
        "我可以帮助回答关于这些服务的任何问题。\n\n"
        "请在您的问题中包含类别，例如：“如何购买 Facebook 账户？”。\n"
        "如果您找不到答案，机器人可以在 3 次失败尝试后建议使用 ChatGPT。"
    )
    return greetings

# Команда /support
@bot.message_handler(commands=['support'])
def handle_support(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    business_connection_id = f"user_{user_id}"
    bc = get_business_connection(business_connection_id)
    user_lang = bc.get('language', 'en') if bc else 'en'
    support_message = {
        'en': "For support, please contact our manager on Telegram: @solomon_bog.",
        'ru': "Для связи с поддержкой (реальным менеджером) перейдите в телеграм: @solomon_bog.",
        'zh': "要联系支持（真实的经理），请转到 Telegram：@solomon_bog。"
    }
    msg = support_message.get(user_lang, support_message['en'])
    # Добавляем эмодзи перед сообщением
    answer = f" {msg}"
    bot.send_message(user_id, answer)

# Команда /chats
@bot.message_handler(commands=['chats'])
def handle_chats(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    if user_id not in ADMIN_USER_IDS:
        # Добавляем эмодзи перед сообщением
        answer = "❌ You do not have access to this command."
        bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
        return

    business_connections = load_business_connections()
    users = []
    for bc_id, data in business_connections.items():
        username = data.get('username', 'Unknown')
        user_chat_id = data.get('user_chat_id')
        if username != 'Unknown':
            business_connection_id = f"user_{user_chat_id}"
            chat_history = get_chat_history(user_chat_id, business_connection_id)
            if chat_history:
                users.append({'id': user_chat_id, 'username': username})

    if not users:
        # Добавляем эмодзи перед сообщением
        answer = " No available chats."
        bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
        return

    # Сортируем пользователей по username
    users = sorted(users, key=lambda x: x['username'])

    # Пагинация: 10 пользователей на страницу
    per_page = 10
    total_pages = (len(users) + per_page - 1) // per_page

    page = 1  # Начальная страница

    def get_users_page(page_num):
        start = (page_num - 1) * per_page
        end = start + per_page
        return users[start:end]

    current_users = get_users_page(page)

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for user in current_users:
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user['username'], callback_data=f"view_chat_{user['id']}")
        markup.add(button)

    # Навигационные кнопки
    nav_buttons = []
    if page > 1:
        nav_buttons.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="⬅️ Previous", callback_data=f"chats_page_{page-1}"))
    if page < total_pages:
        nav_buttons.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Next ➡️", callback_data=f"chats_page_{page+1}"))
    if nav_buttons:
        markup.row(*nav_buttons)

    # Добавляем кнопку выхода в общий список диалогов
    markup.row(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Back to Main Menu", callback_data="back_to_main_menu")
    )

    # Формируем текст сообщения
    text = f" User Chats List (Page {page} of {total_pages}):"

    bot.send_message(user_id, text, reply_markup=markup)

# Обработка нажатий кнопок для /chats, FAQ и GPT
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handle_callback_queries(call):
    if call.data.startswith('chats_page_'):
        # Обработка пагинации в /chats
        try:
            page_num = int(call.data.split('_')[-1])
        except ValueError:
            logging.error(f"Invalid page number in callback data: {call.data}")
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Invalid page number.")
            return

        business_connections = load_business_connections()
        users = []
        for bc_id, data in business_connections.items():
            username = data.get('username', 'Unknown')
            user_chat_id = data.get('user_chat_id')
            if username != 'Unknown':
                business_connection_id = f"user_{user_chat_id}"
                chat_history = get_chat_history(user_chat_id, business_connection_id)
                if chat_history:
                    users.append({'id': user_chat_id, 'username': username})

        if not users:
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, " No available chats.")
            return

        # Сортируем пользователей по username
        users = sorted(users, key=lambda x: x['username'])
        per_page = 10
        total_pages = (len(users) + per_page - 1) // per_page

        current_users = []
        if 1 <= page_num <= total_pages:
            start = (page_num - 1) * per_page
            end = start + per_page
            current_users = users[start:end]
        else:
            logging.error(f"Page number {page_num} out of range.")
            current_users = []

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        for user in current_users:
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user['username'], callback_data=f"view_chat_{user['id']}")
            markup.add(button)

        # Навигационные кнопки
        nav_buttons = []
        if page_num > 1:
            nav_buttons.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="⬅️ Previous", callback_data=f"chats_page_{page_num-1}"))
        if page_num < total_pages:
            nav_buttons.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Next ➡️", callback_data=f"chats_page_{page_num+1}"))
        if nav_buttons:
            markup.row(*nav_buttons)

        # Добавляем кнопку выхода в общий список диалогов
        markup.row(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Back to Main Menu", callback_data="back_to_main_menu")
        )

        # Формируем текст сообщения
        text = f" User Chats List (Page {page_num} of {total_pages}):"

        bot.edit_message_text(
            text,
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            message_id=call.message.message_id,
            reply_markup=markup
        )
    
    elif call.data == 'back_to_main_menu':
        # Обработка кнопки возврата в главное меню
        user_id = call.message.chat.id
        greeting_message = get_greeting_message_all_languages()
        # Добавляем эмодзи в начало сообщения
        message_text = f" {greeting_message}"
        bot.edit_message_text(
            message_text,
            chat_id=user_id,
            message_id=call.message.message_id
        )
    
    elif call.data.startswith('view_chat_'):
        # Обработка просмотра конкретного чата
        try:
            user_id = int(call.data.split('_')[-1])
        except ValueError:
            logging.error(f"Invalid user ID in callback data: {call.data}")
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Invalid user ID.")
            return

        business_connection_id = f"user_{user_id}"
        bc = get_business_connection(business_connection_id)
        if not bc:
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Chat history not found.")
            return

        chat_history = get_chat_history(user_id, business_connection_id)

        if not chat_history:
            # Нет истории диалога
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ This user has no chat history.")
            return

        # Формирование сообщений
        messages = []
        for role, content in chat_history:
            if role == 'assistant':
                messages.append(f" Bot: {content}")
            elif role == 'user':
                username = bc.get('username', 'Unknown')
                messages.append(f" @{username}: {content}")

        full_text = "\n".join(messages)

        # Разделение на страницы
        per_page_chars = 3500  # Установлено меньше максимума для безопасности
        pages = split_text_into_pages(full_text, per_page_chars=per_page_chars)
        total_pages = len(pages)
        current_page = 1

        page_text = pages[current_page - 1]

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        if total_pages > 1:
            markup.row(
                types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Next ➡️", callback_data=f"chat_page_{user_id}_2")
            )
        # Добавляем кнопку возврата в главное меню
        markup.row(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Back to Main Menu", callback_data="back_to_main_menu")
        )

        # Формируем текст сообщения
        text = f" Chat with @{bc.get('username', 'Unknown')}\n\n{page_text}"

        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text, reply_markup=markup)
    
    elif call.data.startswith('chat_page_'):
        # Обработка пагинации внутри чата
        parts = call.data.split('_')
        if len(parts) != 4:
            logging.error(f"Invalid callback data format for chat_page: {call.data}")
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Invalid data format.")
            return
        try:
            user_id = int(parts[2])
            page_num = int(parts[3])
        except ValueError:
            logging.error(f"Invalid user ID or page number in callback data: {call.data}")
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Invalid user ID or page number.")
            return

        business_connection_id = f"user_{user_id}"
        bc = get_business_connection(business_connection_id)
        if not bc:
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Chat history not found.")
            return

        chat_history = get_chat_history(user_id, business_connection_id)

        if not chat_history:
            # Нет истории диалога
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ This user has no chat history.")
            return

        # Формирование сообщений
        messages = []
        for role, content in chat_history:
            if role == 'assistant':
                messages.append(f" Bot: {content}")
            elif role == 'user':
                username = bc.get('username', 'Unknown')
                messages.append(f" @{username}: {content}")

        full_text = "\n".join(messages)

        # Разделение на страницы
        per_page_chars = 3500  # Установлено меньше максимума для безопасности
        pages = split_text_into_pages(full_text, per_page_chars=per_page_chars)
        total_pages = len(pages)

        if page_num < 1 or page_num > len(pages):
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Invalid page number.")
            return

        page_text = pages[page_num - 1]

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        nav_buttons = []
        if page_num > 1:
            nav_buttons.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="⬅️ Previous", callback_data=f"chat_page_{user_id}_{page_num-1}"))
        if page_num < len(pages):
            nav_buttons.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Next ➡️", callback_data=f"chat_page_{user_id}_{page_num+1}"))
        if nav_buttons:
            markup.row(*nav_buttons)
        
        # Добавляем кнопку возврата в главное меню
        markup.row(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Back to Main Menu", callback_data="back_to_main_menu")
        )

        # Формируем текст сообщения
        text = f" Chat with @{bc.get('username', 'Unknown')}\n\n{page_text}"

        bot.edit_message_text(
            text,
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            message_id=call.message.message_id,
            reply_markup=markup
        )
    
    elif call.data.startswith('faq_page_'):
        # Обработка пагинации в FAQ сообщениях
        try:
            parts = call.data.split('_')
            bc_id = parts[2]
            page_num = int(parts[3])
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            logging.error(f"Invalid callback data format for faq_page: {call.data}")
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Invalid data format.")
            return

        business_connection_id = bc_id
        bc = get_business_connection(business_connection_id)
        if not bc:
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ FAQ not found.")
            return

        # Получение faq_pages
        faq_pages = bc.get('faq_pages', [])
        if not faq_pages:
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ FAQ pages not found.")
            return
        if page_num < 1 or page_num > len(faq_pages):
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Invalid page number.")
            return

        page_text = faq_pages[page_num - 1]

        # Создание новой разметки
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        nav_buttons = []
        if page_num > 1:
            nav_buttons.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="⬅️ Previous", callback_data=f"faq_page_{bc_id}_{page_num-1}"))
        if page_num < len(faq_pages):
            nav_buttons.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Next ➡️", callback_data=f"faq_page_{bc_id}_{page_num+1}"))
        if nav_buttons:
            markup.row(*nav_buttons)
        
        # Добавляем кнопку возврата в главное меню
        markup.row(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Back to Main Menu", callback_data="back_to_main_menu")
        )

        # Формируем текст сообщения
        text = f" FAQ (Page {page_num} of {len(faq_pages)}):\n\n{page_text}"

        bot.edit_message_text(
            text,
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            message_id=call.message.message_id,
            reply_markup=markup
        )
    
    else:
        # Необработанные данные callback
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "❌ Invalid action.")
        return

# Команда /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    username = message.from_user.username if message.from_user.username else "Unknown"
    bc_id = f"user_{user_id}"

    if message.content_type == 'text':
        user_text = message.text.strip()
    else:
        user_text = ""

    # Определяем язык на основе команды /start
    user_lang = detect_user_language_robust(message.text)
    logging.debug(f"[handle_start] user_lang={user_lang}")

    update_or_create_business_connection(bc_id, user_chat_id=user_id, date=message.date, username=username, language=user_lang)
    reset_failed_attempts(bc_id)

    # Получаем приветственное сообщение на всех трёх языках
    greeting_message = get_greeting_message_all_languages()

    # Добавляем эмодзи в начало сообщения
    greeting_message = f" {greeting_message}"

    bot.send_message(user_id, greeting_message)

# Обработка сообщений от пользователей
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'video'])
def handle_user_message(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    username = message.from_user.username if message.from_user.username else "Unknown"
    bc_id = f"user_{user_id}"

    if message.content_type == 'text':
        user_text = message.text.strip()
    else:
        user_text = f"User sent {message.content_type}"

    # Определяем язык
    user_lang = detect_user_language_robust(user_text)
    logging.debug(f"[handle_user_message] user_lang={user_lang}")

    # Обновляем информацию о пользователе, включая язык
    update_or_create_business_connection(bc_id, user_chat_id=user_id, date=message.date, username=username, language=user_lang)
    
    # Сохраняем сообщение пользователя
    save_message(user_id, bc_id, 'user', user_text)

    connection = get_business_connection(bc_id)
    if not (connection and connection.get('is_enabled') and connection.get('can_reply')):
        # Добавляем эмодзи перед сообщением
        answer = " Sorry, I can't respond right now."
        bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
        return

    if need_welcome(bc_id):
        # Повторное приветствие (спустя 24 часа)
        greet_text = get_greeting_message_all_languages()
        # Добавляем эмодзи в начало сообщения
        greet_text = f" {greet_text}"
        bot.send_message(user_id, greet_text)

    attempts = get_failed_attempts(bc_id)
    text_lower = user_text.lower()

    # 1) Проверяем GPT ключевые слова
    if user_wants_gpt(text_lower):
        if attempts < 3:
            block_txt = (
                "You can only use GPT after 3 unsuccessful attempts at finding the ready answers.\n"
                "Try rephrasing your question with a specific category first."
            )
            block_tr = google_translate_response(block_txt, user_lang)
            support_msg = get_support_message(user_lang)
            answer = f" {block_tr}\n\n{support_msg}"
            save_message(user_id, bc_id, 'assistant', answer)
            bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
            return
        else:
            trig = get_gpt_trigger_phrase(text_lower)
            if trig:
                try:
                    actual_q = message.text.split(trig, 1)[1].strip()
                except IndexError:
                    actual_q = ""
                if not actual_q:
                    block_txt = (
                        "Please specify your question after the GPT keyword.\n"
                        "For example: `gpt: How to contact bot support?`"
                    )
                    block_tr = google_translate_response(block_txt, user_lang)
                    support_msg = get_support_message(user_lang)
                    answer = f" {block_tr}\n\n{support_msg}"
                    save_message(user_id, bc_id, 'assistant', answer)
                    bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
                    return
            else:
                actual_q = user_text

            gpt_answer = get_gpt_response_simple(actual_q)
            reset_failed_attempts(bc_id)

            suffix = "If you haven't found the answer, manager @solomon_bog will contact you soon!"
            full_ans = gpt_answer + "\n\n" + suffix
            final_ans = google_translate_response(full_ans, user_lang)
            support_msg = get_support_message(user_lang)

            combined_ans = final_ans + "\n\n" + support_msg

            # Разделяем сообщение на страницы
            pages = split_text_into_pages(combined_ans, per_page_chars=3500)
            total_pages = len(pages)

            if total_pages == 1:
                # Одно сообщение
                answer = f" {pages[0]}"
                save_message(user_id, bc_id, 'assistant', answer)
                bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
            else:
                # Несколько отдельных сообщений без кнопок навигации
                for page in pages:
                    answer = f" {page}"
                    save_message(user_id, bc_id, 'assistant', answer)
                    bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
            return

    # 2) Ищем категорию (FAQ)
    cats = load_categories("categories.json")
    found_cat, faq_list = find_category_fuzzy(user_text, cats, threshold=60)

    if not found_cat:
        increment_failed_attempts(bc_id)
        attempts_new = get_failed_attempts(bc_id)

        msg_no_cat = (
            "I can't determine the category of your question. "
            "Please specify, for example: 'How to set up a Facebook account?'."
        )
        if attempts_new >= 4:
            msg_no_cat += (
                "\n\nIt seems we can't find an answer. Now you can use GPT keywords like: "
                "`gpt`, `chat gpt`, `open ai`, `find in gpt`, etc."
            )
        tr_msg = google_translate_response(msg_no_cat, user_lang)
        support_msg = get_support_message(user_lang)
        answer = f" {tr_msg}\n\n{support_msg}"
        save_message(user_id, bc_id, 'assistant', answer)
        bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
        return

    # Если категория найдена, сбрасываем счетчик
    reset_failed_attempts(bc_id)

    # Формируем список FAQ с локализованными метками
    faq_text = build_faq_full_list(found_cat, faq_list, user_lang)
    # Переводим на user_lang
    translated_faq = google_translate_response(faq_text, user_lang)

    # Разделяем на страницы
    pages = split_text_into_pages(translated_faq, per_page_chars=3500)
    total_pages = len(pages)

    if total_pages == 1:
        # Одно сообщение
        answer = f" {pages[0]}"
        save_message(user_id, bc_id, 'assistant', answer)
        bot.send_message(user_id, answer)
    else:
        # Несколько отдельных сообщений без кнопок навигации
        for page in pages:
            answer = f" {page}"
            save_message(user_id, bc_id, 'assistant', answer)
            bot.send_message(user_id, answer)

# Функция для получения сообщения поддержки на нужном языке
def get_support_message(lang):
    support_messages = {
        'en': "For support, please contact our manager on Telegram: @solomon_bog.",
        'ru': "Для связи с поддержкой (реальным менеджером) перейдите в телеграм: @solomon_bog.",
        'zh': "要联系支持（真实的经理），请转到 Telegram：@solomon_bog。"
    }
    return support_messages.get(lang, support_messages['en'])

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 8) Точка входа
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_table()
    logging.info("Deleting webhook (if exists) to enable long polling...")
    bot.delete_webhook()
    logging.info("Starting the bot...")
    bot.infinity_polling()


I tried to check variables in original_text, pre_translated_text, translated and no results.
